# How to get the default frontend language

Tags: multilingual

As the title says, how can I get the default language of my website?

For example, I have Farsi & English language in my website, and Farsi is my default language (but maybe sometimes I want to change it to English).

How can I find out which one is the default one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default language is stored as a parameter in the language component. So you can use this to get the default language: `JComponentHelper::getParams('com_languages')->get('site');`.

For the backend language it would be `JComponentHelper::getParams('com_languages')->get('administrator');`

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla 4:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper;

$defaultFrontendLanguage = ComponentHelper::getParams('com_languages')->get('site');

$defaultBackendLanguage = ComponentHelper::getParams('com_languages')->get('administrator');
```

`$defaultFrontendLanguage` could be a language label like "en-GB";